# grep: excluding lines that begin with a blank character

Tags: grep

I have a text file where some lines have a character at the beginning and some lines don't.  I want to print the text file to screen, excluding the lines that don't have a character at the beginning.

Can I do this with grep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"excluding the lines that don't have a character at the beginning"
```

is same as

```
"including the lines that have the character at the beginning"
```

To get all the lines that start with char `s` you can do:

```
grep '^s' filename
```

Example:

```
[23:18:03][/tmp]$ cat test
stack
overflow
testing
sample
[23:21:37][/tmp]$ grep '^s' test # To list lines beginning with s
stack
sample
```

Comment: similarly, if you had multiple characters that may be at the beginning, you can use a character class:

grep '^[adf]' filename

would match any lines that start with a, d, or f.

Comment: What if I don't know which characters at the beginning?  Is there a way to specify a blank space?

Comment: To list only those lines that do not have a leading space you can use: `grep '^[^ ]' test`